# C# get screenshot of the flash content of the form

Tags: c#, forms, screenshot

EDIT: I try clientRectangle but I get the image from the left superior corner of the desktop and not of the form!
I try to get a screenshot of my form where there is a flash animation. So I try this:

```
Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
bitmap.Save("C:/Users/Public/Documents/YouCam/flash.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
MessageBox.Show("Save");
```

It work, but I get also the border of the form with this. How can I get the inner of the form without the control bar and the borders?
In red the zone that I want to capture:

[image]

Thanks ;)

PS: sorry form my poor english!

Comment: Instead of using the bounds, try the `ClientRectangle`, but you have to transform it to screen coordinates.

Comment: ClientRectangle don't work, I get the superior deskop location...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form's method DrawToBitmap like that:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
        bitmap.Save(@"C:\Deployment\test.bmp");
```

Comment: Did you test this?  Because the user didn't want the borders.

Comment: Yes I try this but, drawtobitmap don't work with a flash animation! Only CopyFromScreen works.

Comment: @Gtazer Your question didn't mention anything about a flash animation.  It's important to properly document your question.

Comment: Yes my bad sorry! So I want to capture my screen with a flash animation in! So I try clientRectangle but I get from the left superior deskop position...